# How can I convert a char-variable value into int?

Tags: java, char

It gives errors at the `q=c[n];` I want the value of `c[n].i` can't access it.

```
public static String aSCII() {

    char c[] = query.toCharArray();
    int q;

    for (int n = 0; n <= query.length(); n++) {
        q = c[n];

        if (q + aSCIIValue > 126) {
            c[n] = (char) (32 + aSCIIValue - (126 - aSCIIValue));
        } else {
            c[n] += aSCIIValue;
        }
    }
}
```

please help me

Comment: "It errors"? Post the error.

Answer (score 1):

Observe the loop:

```
for(int n=0;n<=query.length();n++)
```

it will still run when `n == query.length()`. This will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

A char is already an int, just cast it:

```
q = (int) c[n];
```

Comment: This isn't necessary; Java will promote the char to an int. The OP has some other problem that he hasn't adequately described.